# Jquery change table cell color

Tags: jquery, html

I'm making a table and I want that every time I generate the button "hola", and when I click on it, it set color to the next top cell. I've tried it, but I don't know how I can do it :/

This is my code:

```
<table id = 'tbl'>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Color Rojo!</td>
    <td>Color Azul!</td>
    <td>Color Verde!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Color Rojo!</td>
        <td>Color Azul!</td>
        <td>Color Verde!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Color Rojo!</td>
        <td>Color Azul!</td>
      <td>Color Verde!</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button id = "rojo">Rojo</button></td>
        <td><button id = "azul">Azul</button></td>
        <td><button id = "verde">Verde</button></td>
      </tr> 
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <button id = "tabla">Tabla</button>

$("#tabla").click(function(){
    $("tr").append("<td>Columna Nueva</td>");
    var linea = $('tr:first').html();
    $('#rojo').parent().parent().before('<tr>'+linea+'</tr>');

    $('tr').last().find("td").last().html('<button>hola</button>');
  });
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: there is nothing in your code that actually changes css

Comment: I dont really get what you want either, I believe you might be looking for jQuery's `.eq()`

Comment: your question is not quite clear but I've put your initial code in a fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/G9kr3/

Comment: I got it but I dont know How can I set up the css name in the cell upside every hola button then it makes a diagonal

Comment: You're still not making much sense. 'Upside'? Is that 'above'? You want to color the cells diagonally? Can you provide some illustrations? http://jsfiddle.net/G9kr3/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the one you are looking for:

```
$("#tabla").click(function(){
    $("tr").append("<td>Columna Nueva</td>");
    var linea = $('tr:first').html();
    $('#rojo').parent().parent().before('<tr>'+linea+'</tr>');
    $('tr').last().find("td").last().html('<button class=holaBtn>hola</button>');
  });

$("#tbl").on('click','.holaBtn',function(){
 $(this).parent().parent().prev().find("td").last().css("background","red");
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L5cCT/1/)**

Comment: You are a King! Thank You very Much it helped me!